# Capture/View everything that is printed (POS/Receipt)

Tags: php, windows, printing, invoice

I need a way to capture everything that is printed in my notebook.

### Why?

I have a system, in PHP, and sometimes I need to print **(php_printer)** some invoices, but this costs a lot paper.

*Printing is sent in the background without any popup windows for user confirmation.*

So every time I send something to the printer, the windows (or any application) show me what was sent; or generate a PDF.

The problem is: How can I use this 'alternativa' without changing the printer (driver, etc). Because, if I do that, I need to test in 2 printers, and you know what I mean.

### EscPos

This is the file that I used to print in windows or linux. I develop in windows (requirement of the company) but publish it in a linux server.

**gist:** https://gist.github.com/patrickmaciel/7673875

### What I want

To capture every printed file and save it in a PDF or some driver/application in order to not print the file but rather show it to me on the screen (windows).

### Setup

Dev OS (my): **Windows 7** *(Yes I know, but my employee only works with windows)*
Prod OS: **CentOS**
Printer: **TM-T88IV AFU** (Epson)

Comment: You want to print **and** pdf? or pdf **instead** printing?

Comment: @MeNa print without change my method but capture in background the printed files and save in pdf or show for me in a window, or in another way.

Comment: little change in your code is not an option? i mean, create a pdf with php is not very hard...

Comment: @MeNa Maybe, but I no have idea how to create a PDF file of a POS printer. Fox example, in same size, like a receipt.

Comment: For now are you generate an invoice and send it to php_printer? what is the invoice when you send it to printer? and how do you generate it?

Comment: Could you give us some more background info on how your POS system creates the print job? In some cases capturing and saving a printer spool file may be possible but that highly depends on printers, OS and how a print job is triggered. Could you try to locate the PHP print script?

Comment: @SaschaM78 I add more informations about.

Comment: @MeNa everything is generate and manipulate with PHP and after sent to printer with EscPos file using php_printer (windows) or lpr/cups (linux).

Comment: Have a look at your Output() function starting in line 1069, if you'd add `file_put_contents('/PATH/TO/OUTPUT/FILE', $this->document);` around line 1072 you'd save a copy of each file printed.

Comment: It seems as if there is no Epson->PDF solution at hand, after implementing the mentioned change and having printed a test print, could you post the contents of the created file? That'll help understand the format used and may lead to a solution.

Comment: @SaschaM78 I'll try what you say...

Comment: @SaschaM78 Doesn't work but I create a new action and execute a second operation after print because I think not exist any solution for my problem (monitoring printings in background). Anyway, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my question apparently no solution.

So I just edited it with the class and `EscPos.php` added a method to be executed after printing, writing a simplified way to print invoice in a txt file, which I monitor after filename.txt command `tail-f`.

**Solution code:** https://gist.github.com/patrickmaciel/7677891

Thanks guys.